# ttk treeview: selected color

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

The selected row of my ttk treeview shows as a dark blue background with the text white.

If I set the color of the row with a tag, for example:

```
self.tree.item(item, tags=('oddrow'))
```

and configure the tag as a color, for example:

```
self.tree.tag_configure('oddrow', background='lightgrey')
```

and select the oddrow, the background color does not change (it remains lightgrey) while the text changes from black to white.  How can I get the selected row background to be dark blue, whether or not the row is tagged with a color?

Rows not tagged display as black on white, or when selected as white on dark blue.

I tried

```
ttk.Style().configure('Treeview', selectbackground='blue')
```

but that didn't do anything.

EDIT: I suppose that when I select an item I could re-tag it as not oddrow, then go back when it's un-selected, but that is rather inelegant.

Comment: Did you try `self.tree.tag_configure('oddrow', background='lightgrey', selectbackground='blue')` ?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: _tkinter:TclError: unknown option "-selectbackground"

Comment: Just read the docs at http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M69.  tag only supports foreground, background, font, and image.  Sorry for the bad advice.

Answer (score 5):

From the [TkDocs tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) for trees, it seems you can:

- create a tag with the desired colors (for a selected row)

Then, catch the virtual events from the treeview:

- assign the tag to a row when it gets the focus
- unassign the tag from the row when it loses focus

---

Here's the specific paragraph in the documentation I used:

```
The treeview will generate virtual events "<TreeviewSelect>", "<TreeviewOpen>" 
and "<TreeviewClose>" which allow you to monitor changes to the widget made 
by the user.   You can use the "selection" method to determine the current 
selection (the selection can also be changed from your program).
```

Along with some code from the tutorial:

```
tree.tag_configure('ttk', background='yellow')
tree.tag_bind('ttk', '<1>', itemClicked); # the item clicked can be found via tree.focus()
```

---

note:  I'm not sure this will work.  I'll have to dig up the code to see what I did.

Comment: That's essentially what I ended up doing, as I mentioned rather cryptically in my EDIT.  When a row is selected (monitored with <TreeviewSelect>), I retag all rows with alternate colors (to clear any prior changes), then tag the current row with the plain background so that the default selection color displays properly.

Comment: @foosion -- I meant to suggest tagging/untagging *only* the selected row.  That is, leave all the `oddrow`s tagged the way they are, and add a second tag to the selected row.  The thing I'm not sure about, is what would happen if you have two tags on one row -- which one wins?

Comment: Some of what I'm doing is removing rows, adding rows, moving rows, so retagging everything often makes sense.  Another alternative is to untag the selected row (which makes the selection background look right; alternatively tag it with the selection color), then retag it when the selection changes.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone looking for an answer to change selected color for tkinter treeview, you can check below code.

You have change the state "selected" rather than "active".

```py
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview",
                background="#E1E1E1",
                foreground="#000000",
                rowheight=25,
                fieldbackground="#E1E1E1")
style.map('Treeview', background=[('selected', '#BFBFBF')])
```

Comment: quite irrelevant here

Comment: @AryanFirouzian its not irrelevant, its the **very correct answer**. `style.map('Treeview', background=[('selected', '#dc8c34')])` will change the selected column's color, which is what's asked.

Comment: Thanks, [Durai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10291817/durai). Worked like a charm.